# Could jquery selector select all element with subnode match some condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I have a table with id `tbBookList`, and for each row (`<tr>`), the 4th column (`<td>`) shows a date. I want to remove the all the row with the Date before this year (such as 2016); The Date format is `yyyy-MM-dd` such as 2016-01-24.

I google it but I found I'm hard to describe my question.

The fast way I know is that I can select all row with `$("#tbBookList>tr")` then I can loop it. However, I want to know if there is a better way such as using jquery selector to do that.

Comment: I think for Date comparison in javascript please to look at moment.js

Comment: I think you will have a hard time selecting table rows based on the date content of a cell. Your best bet is looping through the rows and doing the logic in javascript. Selectors are powerful, but not really meant for this kind of conditional logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('#tbBookList tr').filter(function() {
    var cell = $(this).find('td').eq(3);
    var date = cell.text();
    var year = date.split('-').shift();

    return year < 2016;
}).remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. However, it seems it has a tricky point. In order to select the 4th column, I think it use `$(this).find('td').eq(3)`

Comment: @Roy - you're right, `eq` is zero-based, so `0` is the first one, meaning the fourth would be `3`. edited

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you do a loop of all the rows has to occur.

For something like this I would use `filter()` to do the loop rather than `each` but that is personal preference

```
$("#tbBookList>tr").filter(function(){
      var date = $(this).find('td').eq(2).text();
      return SomeTestOfDateValue  // boolean
}).remove();
```